Does gunpowder (black powder) melt when heated?
I was just watching a video about yellow powder (similar formula to black powder, but with potassium carbonate instead of charcoal), and I was wondering:
Does regular black powder melt (and potentially detonate) in the same way when heated?
All I can find readily about melting black powder are questions about water contamination, but that's not what I'm curious about.

And this "same way" is what? I see no point to use carbonate. Sulfur melts easily, but is it even present in this weird mix you mention?

Gunpowder ignites; that's the very purpose of it. Melts, no.

Consider that gunpowder contains elemental carbon, which does not melt at standard pressure -- in fact it sublimes at 3915 K.
Carbon is also insoluble in most everything other than molten metals, such as iron. It certainly would not liquefy in molten sodium nitrate ($\ce{NaNO3}$) or molten sulfur at standard pressure.
